# Getting email addresses from a file using grep with Regex not working?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

So i have a file that contains emails like this :

```
theirEmail@domain.com:theirUsername

theirEmail@domain.com:theirUsername
```

...

i want to extract emails that start with PA and then follow up with 6 random characters, then @gmail.com and after that :theirUsername which is not important for me what the username is.

i tried using this :

```
egrep "^PA[a-zA-Z0-9-.+_]{6}@gmail.com:[a-zA-Z0-9-.+_]+"
```

i tried this with grep and still didn't work
But its not working? its been a long time since i have used regex with egrep and reading the manual didn't help either, what am i doing wrong here? what is the correct way to type it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really just want "6 random characters" and you don't care about what is after the `:` then you can simplify easily.  Don't try to match what's after the `:` at all, and just use a `.` for the characters after PA

```
egrep '^PA.{6}@gmail.com:'
```

e.g.

```
% cat f
hello
PA123456@gmail.com:jgkfd
hello@gmail.com
PA8gk@gmail.com:

% egrep '^PA.{6}@gmail.com:' f
PA123456@gmail.com:jgkfd
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! but can you explain why my regex didn't work? when i use that regex it says invalid range end, what am i doing wrong with that regex?

Comment: The `-` should be the last character in the `[...]` pattern if you want it to be a literal `-`.  So `[a-zA-Z0-9-.+_]` should be `[a-zA-Z0-9.+_-]` instead

Comment: Damn i had no idea order matters inside [ ], so it should always be in that order?

Comment: If you put a `-` in the middle then it thinks it's a range, such as `0-9` or `A-Z`.  By putting it at the end, regexp knows you don't mean a range.